# Почему не изменяется список при использовании forloop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Перед мной стоит задача заменить в каждом элементе списка (при помощи функции `replace()`) одну подстроку на другую. Я это делаю путем перебора каждого элемента списка и замены в нем подстроки при помощи forloop.

```
array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

for a in array:
    a = a.replace("o", "zzzz")
    print(a)

print(array)
```

Однако при выводе каждого элемента списка в цикле и выводе потом отдельно всего списка я вижу что список не изменился:

```
zzzzne
twzzzz
three
fzzzzur
five
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

Так почему список не меняется ?

Answer (score 1):

Просто изменить строки недостаточно. Нужно эти изменённые строки присвоить элементам списка.

Answer (score 0):

```
array = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
for i, a in enumerate(array):
    array[i] = a.replace("o", "zzzz")
    print(array[i])

zzzzne
twzzzz
three
fzzzzur
five

print(array)
['zzzzne', 'twzzzz', 'three', 'fzzzzur', 'five']
```

Comment: Я понимаю каким образом можно решить мою задачу при помощи forloop. Меня интересует по какой причине описанный мной выше способ не изменяет список.

Comment: @BeerBaron потому что вы не изменяли список, вы изменяли только переменную `a`, которая не связана со списком совершенно никак

Comment: @andreymal как я понимаю, переменная `a` является копией элемента списка ?

Comment: @BeerBaron любую переменную в питоне можно рассматривать как ссылку на объект. Переменная `a` изначально ссылается на тот же объект, который хранится в списке, но сам этот объект вы ни капельки не изменили (и строки в питоне изменять в принципе никак нельзя, только создавать новые), вы изменили только ссылку в переменной `a`, которая стала указывать на другой объект (на новую строку), а в списке как лежал старый объект, так и продолжает лежать

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо